# Pivot table in PostgreSQL repeating values in columns

Tags: postgresql, pivot, repeat

Having the following data in a table:
ID --------- Category --------- Value
1234 -------- Cat01 ----------- V001
1234 -------- Cat02 ----------- V002
1234 -------- Cat03 ----------- V003
1234 -------- Cat03 ----------- V004
1234 -------- Cat03 ----------- V005

I want to have the following output:

ID --------- Cat01 --------- Cat02 --------- Cat03
1234 ------- V001 ---------- V002 ---------- V003
1234 ------- V001 ---------- V002 ---------- V004
1234 ------- V001 ---------- V002 ---------- V005

How can it be done in PostgreSQL. As you can see, the value in Cat01 and Cat02 columns are repeated for each entry in Cat03 column
Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you guaranteed to have only 3 categories?

Comment: I have more than 3 categories but the number is fixed, is not dynamic. I have a total of 10 categories. Some categories can have more than one value (like in the example with Cat03) and, for those categories that have one value, repeat the value on the categories that have multiple values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
SELECT a.val AS cat01, b.val AS cat02, c.val AS cat03
FROM
    test_pivot AS a,
    test_pivot AS b,
    test_pivot AS c
WHERE
    a.category = 'Cat01'
    AND
    b.category = 'Cat02'
    AND
    c.category = 'Cat03'
```

Comment: If I dont filter by ID, it will do all combinations and will have more values, right ??

Comment: Yes. I wasn't sure what you meant to do with ID, since your example only has a single value for it.